# Integrating SquareWave - don't understand result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

[Acknowledged as a bug persisting in V12.2]

```
Integrate[SquareWave[t], t] // InputForm
```

Gives as output

```
Piecewise[{{-t, Inequality[1/2, LessEqual, Mod[t, 1], Less, 1]}}, t]
```

I don't understand how this can be the right answer.  For example, substituting in

```
% /. t->19/2
```

gives -19/2, whereas

```
NIntegrate[SquareWave[t], {t, 0, 19/2}]
```

gives 0.5

Edited:

As made clear in the comments below (very informative thank you), there are unavoidable ambiguities in indefinite integrals for functions with branch cuts in the complex plane.

However, as explicitly stated in the documentation, `SquareWave` is only defined for real numbers.  In this case, the result returned by Mathematica seems perverse.  Wouldn't a more appropriate result be

```
TriangleWave[t + 3/4]/4
```

Comment: do `SquareWave[t] // PiecewiseExpand`

Comment: Both answers are right.  An indefinite integral has more than one possible answer.  The fact that the integrand is not continuous complicates things a bit, as the two answer differ by a different constant on each $(k,k+1)$ interval.

Comment: I understand that an indefinite integrals can differ by arbitrary constants, and that the value can depend on the contour chosen across the complex plane (which I don't think can be relevant here).  However, I don't see that finite step change in the integrand should introduce a step change in the integral.

Comment: `Integrate[SquareWave[t], {t, 0, 19/2}]`

Yields $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Not just arbitrary constants, arbitrary *piecewise* constants in general. See e.g. [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/). If you want to try things yourself, plot the result of `Integrate[SquareWave[t], t] - Integrate[PiecewiseExpand[SquareWave[t], 0 < t < 19/2], t]`

Comment: Allow me to cut to the chase: Mathematica is getting it wrong. That's it. This has to do with limitations, no, sorry, "features" in the way Integrals are computed (see the page on the wolfram blog linked above) and in the way piecewise functions are interpreted. The funny thing is that if you are allowed to add piecewise constant of different values to each interval of an integrated piecewise function you can produce virtually any function you like. Just make the piecewise splitting very fine and add or subtract the quantity you need to get the value you desire. Without Dirac's deltas, you can

Comment: I'm not even talking about branch cuts; it is just that *Mathematica* in this case chose the particular integral with the arbitrary piecewise constant you **don't** want.

Comment: @J.M. to clarify, my comment was a general one and not intended to deny anything you wrote. My point is that if I can add arbitrary piecewise constants to a function, I can create any function I want. I can shape the pw constant to make the integral of a square wave look like a sinusoid, or a parabola, or a square wave of different frequency. I just need a finer piecewise subdivision and a suitable piecewise constant. As usual one has to know the lim--- er... features of the software (or of the integration techniques) and do rely on the result before it has been verified.

Comment: @Peltio, my comment was more for the OP than you ("there are unavoidable ambiguities in indefinite integrals for functions with branch cuts in the complex plane"); I'd have directly pinged you otherwise. :) What you say is essentially correct, but with the additional note that although there are many arbitrary piecewise constants that can contort a curve in many ways, the one that guarantees a "reasonable" (whatever the hell that means) result may not be trivial to find.

Comment: Also, I believe that there is a terminology probl--- feature here. The term "square wave" makes one think to a signal - possibly an electric signal. And when you differentiate a signal with a discontinuity (pass a square wave through a capacitor - allow me the loose terminology) you get a pulse in correspondence of the discontinuity (x). Something that the piecewise function is not designed to provide (at least that's what I remember).   (x) Note: incidentally this is one way to measure inductances with a scope: you use a cap to turn a rising edge into a pulse and then measure L's res freq.

Comment: @J.M. Agreed. As a matter of fact, it is not trivial to get that alignment in the shown result. (also, in my previous comment I meant "and do NOT rely on the results..." and the resonant frequency is of the LC tank circuit not L alone - I made two comments using all the chars!!!).

Comment: @JM: can you explain any reason why the result returned is ever desirable, logical or a necessary compromise between conflicting objectives?

Comment: Mathematica help for `Piecewise` says "Integration constants are chosen to make the result continuous".  This seems to suggest that the observed behaviour for `SquareWave` is unintended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram support have confirmed that

```
TriangleWave[t+3/4]/4
```

would be a more appropriate result for

```
Integrate[SquareWave[t], t]
```

EDIT

This problem remains in V12.2

Answer (score 2):

May be it will help if you look at the plots:

```
Plot[SquareWave[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Integrate[SquareWave[t], t]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't agree with the values I get using NIntegrate

Comment: @mikado, then your question is not complete, and it should be edited.

Comment: @mikado Szabolcs answered your addendum for agreement with `NIntegrate`. The discrepancy is also discussed in this "MathWorld" page: ["Indefinite Integral"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteIntegral.html).

Answer (score 2):

One problem with picking a constant at each discontinuity is that there are infinitely many discontinuities.  In general, this couldn't be done, so returning a mathematically correct answer would be the next best thing.  In the `SquareWave[]` case, some cleverness leads some to realize that there is a way to choose the constants or even an antiderivative expression (in terms of`TriangleWave[]`).  One might hope this could be handled (eventually) by a special rule for `SquareWave[]`.

You can get a continuous result by restricting the domain, thereby restricting the number of discontinuities.  The answer is valid only over the domain, however.

```
Assuming[{0 < t < 10},
 Integrate[SquareWave[t], t]
 ]
Plot[%, {t, 0, 10}]
```

> `Out[]=` [large piecewise function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZjzs.png)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to weigh in that this is one of the reasons I don't like indefinite integrals most of the time. I much prefer to consider definite integrals with the upper limit as a variable, since that fixes the whole off-by-a-constant (or constants-on-each-piecewise-segment, as we're seeing here) problem and replaces it with the much more intuitive question of "where do I put the lower limit?".

Unfortunately, it seems that Mathematica can't deal with this kind of integral right now, even though it's perfectly well-defined:

```
Assuming[t > 0,
  Integrate[SquareWave[\[FormalT]], {\[FormalT], 0, t}]
]
```

> (* returns unevaluated *)