# Is Mathematica doing this integral of a wave form approximation correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate a square wave approximation I found in this [answer by ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38295/328).

Nothing wrong with the answer but when I try to integrate it I run into trouble.

I modified the code from the answer and first wrote this:

```
Clear[squareWave, integratedSquareWave, x, coefficient, delta];
coefficient = 10000;
delta = 1000;
squareWave[x_] = 2 ArcTan[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*coefficient]/\[Pi];
ListLinePlot[Table[squareWave[x], {x, 0, 2, 1/delta}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

This gives the nice plot:

[image: square wave]

as I wanted.

Then I do the **numeric** integral of the square wave above with this code:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Accumulate[Table[squareWave[x], {x, 0, 2, 1/delta}]]/delta, 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

which gives the school example plot:

[image: numeric integral of square wave]

So far so good. But now I try to plot the **symbolic** integral of the square wave:

```
integratedSquareWave[x_] = 
  Integrate[2 ArcTan[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*coefficient]/\[Pi], x];
ListLinePlot[Table[Re[integratedSquareWave[x]], {x, 0, 2, 1/delta}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

and then I get this:

[image: symbolic integral of square wave]

**Question:**

> Is this symbolic integral correct? The numeric integral looks so different from the symbolic integral.

The symbolic integral which correctness I am asking about can be found with this command:

```
Clear[x];
coefficient = 10000;
Integrate[2 ArcTan[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*coefficient]/\[Pi], x]
```

Also I had to take the real part `Re` of the symbolic integral in order to be able to plot it.

All three plots in one block of code:

```
Clear[squareWave, integratedSquareWave, x, coefficient, delta];
coefficient = 10000;
delta = 1000;
squareWave[x_] = 2 ArcTan[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*coefficient]/\[Pi];
ListLinePlot[Table[squareWave[x], {x, 0, 2, 1/delta}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]] 
ListLinePlot[
 Accumulate[Table[squareWave[x], {x, 0, 2, 1/delta}]]/delta, 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
integratedSquareWave[x_] = 
  Integrate[2 ArcTan[Sin[2 \[Pi] x]*10000]/\[Pi], x];
ListLinePlot[Table[Re[integratedSquareWave[x]], {x, 0, 2, 1/delta}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

Comment: The symbolic integral is not entirely correct, but it would be correct if the discontinuities at integers and integer multiples of $\pi/4$ would be removed. Apparently, `Integrate` has problems determining the correct braches of some inverse trigonometric functions...

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117770)?

Comment: No I had not seen that question.